Android download manager - unsupported file type message on notification tap
My code to enqueue download:
await AndroidDownloadManager.enqueue(downloadUrl: url, downloadPath: destDir!, fileName: fileName, headers: headers, notificationVisibility: NotificationVisibility.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);

After file downloaded (no errors), it shows notification with message saying download is complete. In my case, jpg file has been downloaded, so after notifcation tap it should be opened. But after notification tap, file won't open and I'm getting this:

Content handling failed! [CONTEXT service_id=198 ]
cmyr: Not supported file: IMG_20200720_101116.jpg
 at cnba.onResume(:com.google.android.gms@241518041@24.15.18 (190800-627556096):705)
 at fr.e(:com.google.android.gms@241518041@24.15.18 (190800-627556096):455)
 at gv.a(:com.google.android.gms@241518041@24.15.18 (190800-627556096):11)
 at ha.e(:com.google.android.gms@241518041@24.15.18 (190800-627556096):101)
 at ha.g(:com.google.android.gms@241518041@24.15.18 (190800-627556096):1495)
 at fi.aJ(:com.google.android.gms@241518041@24.15.18 (190800-627556096):1184)
 at fi.aL(:com.google.android.gms@241518041@24.15.18 (190800-627556096):83)
 at fi.am(:com.google.android.gms@241518041@24.15.18 (190800-627556096):73)
 at et.run(:com.google.android.gms@241518041@24.15.18 (190800-627556096):4)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at bnbb.nx(:com.google.android.gms@241518041@24.15.18 (190800-627556096):1)
 at bnbb.dispatchMessage(:com.google.android.gms@241518041@24.15.18 (190800-627556096):138)
 at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

Why .jpg file is considered as unsupported and how to make it openning as image?
I use this plugin https://pub.dev/packages/android_download_manager to download file via native android download manager.
